Node.js cluster with pm2, socket.io (and redis) - client can't connect to socket server
I have a node.js express app with socket.io and now I want to scale it a little and run it in a cluster using pm2.
In order to do so, I have already extracted some functions (like cronjob handling) into a dedicated server so the clustering won't bring any issues here.
But I'm totally struggling to get socket.io to work in cluster-mode. I think I have tried every feasible approach and followed the official guide from socket.io. But neither of the following worked for me:

use @socket.io/pm2, @socket.io/cluster-adapter and @socket.io/sticky as the official guide says
use pm2, @socket.io/redis-adapter with my redis server (and @socket.io/sticky)
set the transports: ["websocket"] option on client-side to disable long-polling (also as mentioned in the offical guide). this seems to work, but whats the sense of the other modules if this is the only one that works?

On the client, i always get a http 400 with "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established." or "session id unknown".
The call to http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?userID=33&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P8W16q5&sid=j_OJRVATLbqhDLOXAABq returns: {"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}
This is part of my server.js
const server = createServer(app)
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`App is running on port ${port} http...`));
setupSocketIo(server);

And this my websocket.js (currently with the redis-adapter approach):
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import { instrument } from "@socket.io/admin-ui";
import { getDbConnectionStatus } from './sequelize/connectionStatus.js';
import { createAdapter } from '@socket.io/redis-adapter';
import { connectRedis, redisPublisher, redisSubscriber } from './redisClient.js';

const socketConfig = {
    io: null
};

redisSubscriber.subscribe("ws", (message) => {
    if(socketConfig.io){
        socketConfig.io.emit("Notification", message);
    }
});

const setupSocketIo = async (server) => {
    await connectRedis();
    const socketServerOptions = {
        cors: {
            origin: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/" : "http://localhost:3000",
            methods: ["GET", "POST"]
        }
    };
    if (process.env.exec_mode && process.env.exec_mode === "cluster_mode") {
        console.log("Cluster mode");
        socketServerOptions.adapter = createAdapter(redisPublisher, redisSubscriber);
    }

    socketConfig.io = new Server(server, socketServerOptions);

    socketConfig.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        const userID = socket.handshake.query.userID;
        // Join the user's private room
        socket.join(userID);

        //Send the current database connection status to the user
        socket.emit('dbConnection', getDbConnectionStatus());
    });

    // Enable the admin UI
    instrument(socketConfig.io, {
        auth: false,
        mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "production" : "development",
    });

};

export { setupSocketIo, socketConfig };

I assume, the "session id unknown" error occurs because the request is not routed to the same instance and none of the other instances know about the session (shouldn't this be purpose of redis here?). So I added @socket.io/sticky and setupWorker(socketConfig.io); even though this is not mentioned in the redis-adapter guide from the socket.io team.
Now after multiple connection attempts and "session id unknown" errors, it seems to work and connects successfully. But still the first message from the on connect listener is lost.
Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong here? Does it take some time until sticky knows which instance should receive the request? Are like 15 failed connection attempts normal until a connection is established?
